# Email Template Go High Level

Tags: html, email, handlebars.js, html-email, crm

I'm creating an HTML email template from scratch in GHL. The email template is designed to fetch information submitted from a form, which includes a custom field for uploading multiple images. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to retrieve all the images uploaded to that custom field. It appears that the images are not stored in an array, causing problems when I attempt to access them individually.

The custom field, {{contact.upload_image_1}}, works as expected. However, when I try {{contact.upload_image_1[0]}}, it results in a variable issue. I've also attempted to use an "each" loop, which works but only retrieves one image.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this issue.

```
{{#each contact.upload_image_1}}
   <img src="{{this}}" alt="Uploaded Image">
 {{/each}}
```

I also tried this but it screams that there's a variable issue.

```
{{#each contact.upload_image_1 as image}}
 <a href="{{image}}">Image</a>
{{/each}}
```

I also did a length check but it doesn't return a vavlue

```
{{contact.upload_image_1.length}}
```